# PhpStorm can't load the php.page even after setting include paths

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I just started out my journey in learning more about programming in PHP - PDO style. I've just installed PhpStorm on my PC to serve as IDE.

I'm now stuck at why PhpStorm can't identify where the included php file is. I did my research and I noticed that others also encountered the same problem when they first used PhpStorm.

I am getting

`Warning: include(): Failed opening '../controller_admin.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\Users\Jordan\PhpstormProjects\cai\view\view_admin\admin_accountmanagement.php on line 6`

It appears that the **root** of all included directories/file starts in `C:\xampp\php\PEAR` which appears to be the default since I'm using `XAMPP`. But in my case, I created my project folder in `C:\Users\Jordan\PhpStormProjects\cai`

I did my research and I found different suggestions and possible solutions.

Some of which are :

1. Editing of php.ini include path (which I didn't do because I want to fix it within PHPStorm instead of modifying the `php.ini`)
2. Setting the include path in PhpStorm's PHP Setting like so

   [image]
3. Using `set_include_path()` method in index.php
4. Adding the project in `C:\xampp\php\PEAR\projectfolderhere` which *limits my flexibility* of putting the project folder somewhere else. (I don't like this solution)

My include statement:

```
<?php var_dump(get_include_path())?> //returns ".;C:\xampp\php\PEAR" in browser
<?php include('controller/controller_admin.php')?>
```

`controller` directory is `C:\Users\Jordan\PhpStormProjects\cai\controller`

I wonder why is it that even after adding the project's root folder directory to PhpStorm's Include Path settings it still can't reference or see the project folder and sub folders.

Comment: Just to clarify: the script runs fine through the web server but you're getting that warning from within the IDE? What menu or keyboard short-cut are you using to get the error?

Comment: That "Include path" in PhpStorm settings is for IDE ONLY (for including 3rd part libraries) -- it does not affect PHP code execution in any way. It has to be fixed 1) in your code (e.g. use absolute or proper relative path in your `include`/`require` statements) or 2) in php.ini (which is not desired for your case since you are including some this-project-specific files). `set_include_path()` will also work but not ideal. #1 is much better/reliable.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I'm getting the warning message in the browser. The IDE lets me launch the page without an error. Any ideas?

Comment: @LazyOne Does it mean I have error in the path `../controller_admin.php` I put in `include()`? Does getting `.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR` when I `var_dump(get_include_path())` doesn't have anything to do with the error?

Comment: `.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR` is a **default** `include_path` content on Windows. I suggest defining a constant somewhere (e.g. in entry point file or some file that always gets included) that points to the project root and use it in your include/require statements, e.g. `include(DIR_ROOT . '/controller/controller_admin.php');` You may also consider class autoloading (e.g. custom one or composer one) -- minimal include/require usage then...

Comment: @LazyOne Alright, I'll try that. Including it in some entry point file sounds a good idea. Thank you.

Comment: @LazyOne You were right, I inspected the path and found what's causing it. It's now working. thanks.